# Change text color based on value

Tags: php

I'm just trying to display the results in red or green depending on their value. Negative or Positive.
I have the following code but it is just not working. Can anyone please help?

```
<?php
            $total = 0;
            $index = 0;
                foreach($products as $product){
                    $index ++;
                    ?>
                    
                    <tr>
                    <?php
                        $style = ($total < 0) ? "color:red; font-weight:bold;" : "color:green; font-weight:bold;";
                    ?>
                    
                        <td class="text-center" style="<?php echo $style ?>" >
                        <?php
                            $total_item = $product['quantity'] * $product['sale_price'];
                            $total += $total_item;
                            if ($index == count($products)) {
                                
                            echo formatcurrency ($total);
                            }
                        ?>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                <?php
                }
        ?>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u7ptK.png)

My original code was this here, but i only wanted the last value to be displayed so I modified to the code above. Now i need to display in RED if negative or Green if positive.

```
<table>
      <?php
       $total = 0;
       foreach($products as $product){  
       ?>
       <tr>
           <td>...</td>
           <td>...</td>
           <td>
      <?php
        $total_item = $product['quantity'] * $product['sale_price'];
        $total += $total_item;
        echo formatcurrency($total);  
      ?>
        </td>
      </tr>
  <?php
  }
  ?>
```

... ... $-225.00
... ... $-755.00
... ... $-665.00

Comment: Are you sure `$total` is actually fluctuating between negative and positive?

Comment: $total is actually the last result that I want to display when i calculate the balance from the values of the picture attached.

Comment: So, the image is what you _want_ to happen? In that case, what _does_ happen? "It's just not working" is not a helpful problem description. It would also be very useful if you could [edit] your sample code to be a [mre] - add some example input for the `$products` array, and remove references to code that's not included, such as the `formatcurrency` function.

Comment: A cursory look at the code tells me that `$total` is initialized with a value of 0 and never decreases. Why would you expect it to ever be below 0?